# Trouble importing a Python module

Tags: python, import, module

I have a Python project with 2 files:
epic.py
site.py

in the epic.py I have the lines

```
from site import *
bark()
```

in site.py I have the lines

```
def bark():
    print('arf!')
```

when I try to run epic.py, it returns "bark is not defined" 
this is weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try renaming site.py to mysite.py or something like that because there is a standard Python `site` module.

Comment: No wonder I didn't find anything about it in the documentation..
Is there a short list of forbidden names ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/ - using a quick search at the left displays everything related to that (first result with 'site' was the module)

Comment: You can always try importing the name to check it before using it. You can also call `dir()` on the imported module to see if the functions in the module are what you would expect them to be.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `site` is also the name of a built-in module. You weren't really importing your custom `site` module. If you change the name to, say, `site_.py` and import accordingly, it'll work.